Unable to import Airflow into dag
When trying to install airflow via pip install airflow it returns Please install package apache-airflow instead of airflow.
Installing apache-airflow works, but when trying to from apache-airflow import DAG the hyphen causes an invalid syntax error and from airflow import DAG does not resolve airflow.
How do I include Airflow libraries when making my dag?

"does not resolve" -- what does that mean, exactly?  Don't make us guess.  Please show the exact error message.

The name of the package that is installed with pip is not always exactly the same name as the package that is imported in the code, as you found out with apache-airflow.  In this case, it should just be airflow.

@JohnGordon Does not resolve refers to the error message here Import "airflow" could not be resolved PylancereportMissingImports

That is only a warning message from pylance.  Are you getting an actual python error?

Use following steps :

Install Airflow: Use pip install apache-airflow.

Import in Code: Use from airflow import DAG (not apache-airflow).

Test Installation: Run airflow version to confirm.

Place DAG: Save your DAG in ~/airflow/dags/ and start the webserver with airflow webserver and airflow scheduler.


